# linux kernel module memory management

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm experimenting with memory management in linux kernel modules and I was wondering why a thread does not see the same memory as the module's functions. What I mean is,

I have a `int *x` declared globally. I allocate space using kmalloc and assign 10 to it. Now when I try and access it from within a thread, I get a totally different value.

Why does this happen? How can I get around this?

**EDIT:**

I run my programs in x86 architecture on a single core (on a VM).

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/94qGc6ZQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SMP architectures values that are cached are not updated across all cores so a thread on another core can be using a stale value.

Another issue you can have is concurrent access between threads that means Thread 1 read x before Thread 2 was able write x but Thread 2 continued and said x = 10 but Thread 1 is still using the old value when x was uninitialized.

The way to solve the second problem (which seems more likely) is to use locking to control access to that variable so only 1 thread can modify/read it at a time to avoid issues of stale values.

(Not hardware kernel module so don't use volatile ;P) use suggestion of smp_wb and smp_rb below.

EDIT: Looks like my first suggestion was right. So to solve this you can use smp_wb on x before doing kmalloc and assignment. Then a read barrier on x before attempting to print the value of x. This effectively tells the CPU read the new value because it might be bad or could have been reordered in access. You may be able to just use a read barrier on the other thread but for safety use barriers where access is done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The value is not set by a thread, it is done my the module init function. I've updated the question showing some code. I'll check if volatile does anything.

Comment: what value is it getting instead of 10?

Comment: So it looks like I was right with my first guess. kthread_run is dropping that thread on another CPU or core and the cache has a different value for x. Look at KarlP's answer.

Comment: Here is more :-) http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt

Comment: @KarlP I know you usually don't want to use volatile unless it's microcontroller based things (really the only place I use them). Just the easiest thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of lock (and memory barrier that invalidates the cache.)

On SMP kernels, there are lock mechanisms implemented (for the kernel) that takes care of this:

Read http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt
and especially "Inter-CPU locking barrier effects"

Comment: Thanks for that link - it definitely helped me understand it a bit more. But I'm not sure how to solve my problem now. Why does it happen? Is it because of out of order execution?

Comment: It happens because of out of order execution and because of caching. So what happens is that the memory accesses get reordered in a way that caches int *x to some random value determined by where it gets loaded in memory. You change that value on another core and then when your thread executes its using a stale cached value. To fix it we cause the CPU to invalidate the cache that contains int *x and read in a more current value.

Answer (score 1):

What architecture are you running on?  I don't believe the other answers that say you are hitting memory ordering problems or cache coherency problems, because

- x86 is very strongly ordered, and `kthread_run()` internally takes so many locks etc. that I'm sure there is the equivalent of a memory barrier between the assignment to *x and the start of your thread.  So even on more weakly ordered architectures, I don't think you are really missing a memory barrier.
- I don't believe there is *any* architecture where Linux runs that is cache-incoherent between CPUs.  You have to be careful with external devices doing DMA into memory, but that's completely different from the issue here.

In other words I think the code as you have written it in your question looks fine.  I suspect that this is boiled down from your real code, and in so doing you got rid of the real bug.

It certainly is true that if you have code that modifies a variable used in your thread *after* the `kthread_run` then you have a race condition which could lead to a bug like what you see here.

Comment: Interesting. But what I've shown is pretty much all of my program. I've edited the question with a link to my whole program. Also, I found out that if I create another thread after this, the output by the thread is 10! Strange.

Comment: Your code doesn't build for me (I needed `#include <linux/slab.h>` to get a declaration of `kmalloc`) but once I fixed that, it printed `mem_test: thread: value 10` on a real system (running kernel version 3.0).  Not sure what your bug might be.

Comment: +1 : True. I see that my answer is blabbing about memory barriers when I really is suggesting a lock (that will implement a mb too)